# How to verify password whith 2 different forms?

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 forms : one for Registration and one for Login ([not on the same page, one is a modal][1])

(That's why I did 2 issets at the beginning)

The Registration one is working.

However the Login doesn't work because a User can log in with any password.

I want to verify username/email and of course password. How can I do it ?

Thank you!

Here is my code :

```
    // REGISTRATION
    if (isset($_POST['reg_user']) || isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['name']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
        
        $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM utilisateur WHERE pseudoUtil='$username' OR mailUtil='$email'";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1){
            $_SESSION['message'] = "User already exists !"; 
        }
        else{
            mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO utilisateur (pseudoUtil, mailUtil, pwdUtil) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$hashed_password')");
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Registration complete :)"; 
        }

        // LOGIN
        if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
                        
                
            $query2 = "SELECT $hashed_password FROM utilisateur WHERE pseudoUtil='$username' OR mailUtil='$email'";
            $results2 = mysqli_query($db, $query2);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($results2) == 1){
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                header('location: index.php'); 
            }
            else{
            }
        }
    }
    else{
    }

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCdAV.png
```

Comment: registration needs to create the password hash and save it to the database, log in needs to pull the hash from the database and compare to the password

Comment: Why is your `// LOGIN` code _inside_ the if condition you have wrapped around the whole `// REGISTRATION` process, to begin with?

Comment: You should stop using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` as it's [not as secure as you might think](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391315/is-mysqli-real-escape-string-enough-to-avoid-sql-injection-or-other-sql-attack). Use prepared statements using placeholders instead. You can read [how to prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to get a quick example of how to use them. Also, _never_ escape or change the users password. Just create a hash from the password "as-is" and store that hash.

Comment: `password_verify($password, $hashed_password)` will _always_ be true. `$password` contains the value sent in `$_POST['password']` and `$hashed_password` is the hash of `$password` (created on the 7th line in the posted code). So you're just comparing the posted password against itself (which obviously will always be a match)

Comment: @CBroe because i had to use the $hashed_password variable created in the Registration

Comment: That is one of the worst justifications I have ever heard. Plus, what you are doing, does not even make sense. You create `$hashed_password` based on `$password`, and then later on you do `password_verify($password, $hashed_password)` - you did not even read the actual hashed password of the user from the database here, you are comparing two hashes calculated on the _same_ input variable.

Comment: I updated the code. However i am still having trouble with `mysqli_num_rows($results2) == 1`.  I have this error message : **Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_num_rows(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given**

Comment: Google that error message and you'll soon find existing explanations for it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use PHP's password\_hash to hash and verify passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords)

Answer (score 0):

registration needs to create the password hash and save it to the database, log in needs to pull the hash from the database and compare to the password

both of these tasks should be complete isolated from each other

this means your code should look more like this
note this is an example only not tested as working

`POST /register body: username=someone@some.where&password=123456789`

```
function Register(){
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT count * as count FROM users WHERE email=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST["username"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    
    if($result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)["count"]>0)
    {
        return "User already exists"
    }
    else
    {
        $hash = password_hash($_POST["password"],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) values (?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST["username"], $hash);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        //either return success or set up as a successful login and perform login action
    }
 }
```

`POST /login body: username=someone@some.where&password=123456789`

```
 function Login(){
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT hash FROM users WHERE email=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST["username"]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    
    if(password_verify($_POST["password"], $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)["hash"]))
    {
        //do successful login 
    }
    else
    {
        //log in failed
    }
 }
```